# What is the most effective way of remotely controlling the hosts file?

Tags: symbolic-link, remote, hosts, hosts-file

I need to control the `hosts` file on other Windows machines. I have administrator access on those machines and can install anything, the only question is — what to install? Ideally I would simply make a symlink to the `hosts` file and put it into Dropbox, but unfortunately it turns out you cannot create symlinks for this file. What is the alternative?

Upd: just in case anyone's wondering why I cannot simply do it at hardware (router) level, turns out cheap consumer-grade Made in China routers have really bad admin interfaces, hardly anything works, so that's not an option.

Comment: Something lime puppet vpild help, but is probably overkill. Why not Fitch reliance on hosts file and fix DNS?

Comment: @davidgo I don't understand the second part of what you wrote.

Comment: @davidgo: Your smartphone took some liberties with your words.

Comment: When do you want to update it?  While running or could you copy a replacement file on boot for example?

Comment: @lx07 I want to disable/redirect certain DNS entries, but I need to do this temporarily, not permanently. reboot won't work.

Comment: Sorry - I was trying to suggest the use of "puppet" to manage hosts files, although it it is probably overkill. Why not ditch reliance on the hosts files and use appropriate DNS infrastructure instead?

Comment: @davidgo it's a home set-up, so I'm trying not to overcomplicate things. ideally this would be done in the router but that's not an option here.

Comment: What model rputer? If your time is worth anything, replace the router with one that has the functionality you need. The alternative would be to set up your own  name server and set this for all your devices. Generally this is done in conjunction with dhcp by the router using dnsmasq (which is Unix/Linux software)